# Finding the smallest number not smaller than x for a rolling data of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Let suppose i have data in rows for a column(O) : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
Its average is 5.5.
I need to find the smallest number which is larger than the average 5.5 :- i.e. '6'

Here is what I have tried soo far.

method 1:

```
df["test1"] = df["O"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).nlargest(5).iloc[-1])
```

Discarded as that number may not always be the 6th number.

method 2:

```
great = []
df['test1'] = ''
df["avg"] = df["O"].shift().rolling(min_periods=1, window=10).mean()
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    for j in range(0, 10):
        if(df.loc[i-j, 'O'] > df.loc[i, 'avg']):
            great.append(df.loc[i-j, 'O'])
    df.loc[i, 'test1'] = min(great)
```

This throws an error:

> KeyError: -1

Please help to find the small error in the code as soon as possible.

Thanks,
D.

Comment: please help, its urgent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
n = 10
output = df.vals.rolling(10).apply(lambda x : x[x>x.mean()].min())
```

Answer (score 4):

Mask the Series when it is greater than the mean, then sort, then take the first row.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], columns=("vals",))
df[df.vals > df.vals.mean()].sort_values("vals").head(1)
# >     vals
#    5  6
```

Comment: While this will work for 10 data, can you help if this was for a rolling window of 10 data?

Comment: @BENY 's answer seems to be what you needed.

Comment: Nothing is happening by @BENY 's answer. It is showing ValueError. any alternative?

Comment: BENY's answer is working perfectly. The reason for your error seems external to the description and the kind of data you gave. Please provide a reproducible example raising your error, so we may help you.

Comment: I restarted Kernel several times and now it works, thanks.